# Get attribute values to the XML-File

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I got a issue with XML, and write some information on a XML-file.  
I got several xsd-files describing my XML. I created one big .cs-file with `"xsd/c testfile1.xsd testFile2.xsd..."` etc. And everything went nice and looks good.  
But if I take one created class i.e. testfile1.xsd, it looks like 
`"<xs:complexType name="Header">"` and inside that one there is this some ordinary xs:element and stuff, but also this: `"<xs:attribute name="version" default="1.0.0.0"/>"`. This is translated to:

```
"public Header() {
 this.versionField = "1.0.0.0";}"
```

in the generated class 'Header'. And it got as well this field: `private string versionField;`

. (There is of course a couple of other private fields as well, but those works good.). So I create instances of all classes, fill them with data and write it as an XML-file with this:

```
 - XmlSerializer XmlSerRoot = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RootInformation))
   (the root of my xml!) 
 - StringWriterWithEncoding strWriter = new StringWriterWithEncoding(Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
 - XmlDocument documentInXML = new XmlDocument();
 - XmlSerRoot.Serialize(strWriter, rootInformation); (Here is the XML, filled with values, and the Header.version got the value 1.0.0.0) 
 - string XmlString;
 - XmlString = strWriter.ToString(); (Here I can look at the created xml when debugging in VS and now the version-information is gone)
 - documentInXML.LoadXml(XmlString);
 - documentInXML.Save(myPath);
```

But when I look at the xml-file this `<Header>` is not have anything like version. I want i to look like: `<Header version="1.0.0.0">`    
I even tried to do it in code like:

```
Header header = new Header(); 
header.version = header.version; 
and
with header.version = "1.0.0.0";
```

But still it's no version-text in the tag. All other tags got their value. Just this `<Header>` loose this extra information.    
Does someone got a tip? There is a lot of places I need this to work. Everything else is just working fine.

Regards, /E

Here is an piece of example-code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
namespace TestAppXML
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RootInfo rootInfo = new RootInfo();
            rootInfo.RootText = "This is the Root!";
            Header header = new Header();
            header.TestHeader = "This is HeaderText!";
            rootInfo.Header = header;
            XmlSerializer XmlSerRoot = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RootInfo));
            StringWriterWithEncoding strWriter = new StringWriterWithEncoding(Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
            XmlDocument documentInXML = new XmlDocument();
            XmlSerRoot.Serialize(strWriter, rootInfo);
            string XmlString;
            XmlString = strWriter.ToString();
            documentInXML.LoadXml(XmlString);
            strWriter.Close();
            documentInXML.Save(@"C:\TestXml.xml");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://acme.com")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://acme.com", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class RootInfo
    {
        private Header headerField;
        private string rootTextField;
        public Header Header
        {
            get { return this.headerField; }
            set { this.headerField = value; }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "normalizedString")]
        public string RootText
        {
            get { return this.rootTextField; }
            set { this.rootTextField = value; }
        }
    }

        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
        [System.SerializableAttribute()]
        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
        [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://acme.com")]
        public partial class Header
        {
            private string testHeaderField;
            private string versionField;
            public Header()
            {
                this.versionField = "1.0.0.0";
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "normalizedString")]
            public string TestHeader
            {
                get { return this.testHeaderField; }
                set { this.testHeaderField = value; }
            }

            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
            [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute("1.0.0.0")]
            public string version
            {
                get { return this.versionField; }
                set { this.versionField = value; }
            }
        }
        class StringWriterWithEncoding : StringWriter
        {
            private Encoding MyEncoding;
            public StringWriterWithEncoding(Encoding encoding)
                : base()
            {MyEncoding = encoding;}
            public override Encoding Encoding
            {
                get{return MyEncoding;}
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you paste the actual code, you are using.

Comment: Ok, I put in a small example where this version-text is not in the xml-file.
Regards, /E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I think I knov the issue. It's because this xsd.exe creates 'DefaultValueAttribute' for those fields. That prevent this field to be in the xml. Maybe some xsd-switch could have done that, I dunno...